# How do you snapshot test components with actions from Redux connect?

Tags: redux, react-redux, jestjs

I want to snapshot test a react component that dispatches a redux action in its `componentDidMount()` handler.  The action is given to the component through Redux's `connect()`.

How should I mock the action?

Right now the action is imported in the component (see Newsfeed.js below). So how would I swap it out for a mock action in my test?

I'm using redux-thunk for my async actions, but that shouldn't matter much.

**app/components/Newsfeed.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

// An action that makes an async request to get data
import { loadNewsfeedStories } from '../actions/Newsfeed';

class Newsfeed extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.loadNewsfeedStories();
  }

  ...
}

export default connect(state => ({
  stories: state.newsfeed.stories
}),
{
  loadNewsfeedStories
})(Newsfeed)
```

**app/tests/Newsfeed.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

// This creates a mockStore using my reducers and a saved JSON state.
import { mockStore } from './MockState';

// The component to test
import Newsfeed from '../components/Newsfeed';

test('Newsfeed matches snapshot', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={mockStore}>
      <Newsfeed />
    </Provider>
  );

  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

**Possible Solutions**

1. Export the unconnected component, and manually pass in all props & mock actions. Will be a lot of extra coding compared to just using the mockStore & provider.  Also we won't be testing the 'connected' component.
2. Use something like [Nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock)? Seems to intercept HTTP calls, so the ajax requests wouldn't actually go anywhere.
3. For axios, there is a lib called moxios - https://github.com/mzabriskie/moxios

Answer (score 0):

You could try exporting a different connected component, but with a mocked "mapDispatchToProps" function. This way, no action will get through.

But personally, when testing components. I write a mock reducer, these should not change the state but record all dispatched actions (Jests mock functions are very useful for this). This way, you can also test if the correct action is dispatched when clicking a button,...

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to test the component, redux store, and mock http requests at the same time because unit tests should be small.

Another option would be to avoid executing business logic in `componentDidMount`.
Instead of writing

`componentDidMount(){
  this.props.loadNewsfeedStories();
}`

You can move this logic to the redux module (depends on libs you use).
If you use only redux-thunk without libraries like saga or redux-logic, you can use this https://github.com/Rezonans/redux-async-connect.

> but record all dispatched actions

Redux thunks are hard to test. Your mock dispatcher will receive only an array of functions. And you can't verify if a function was created by `loadNewsfeedStories()` or by `someAnotherThunk()`.